Opening Modal from Sidebar in Google App Script
I'm building a Google Docs Add-on using Google App Script and the React-Google-Apps-Script template. I have a task to display a list of dynamic items in the sidebar, with each item being editable in a modal window. This means I need to trigger a modal from the sidebar and pass a key to it. Is this functionality achievable? Specifically, from the sidebar component, I need to run the openDialog function, which contains server-side code.
export const openDialog = () => {
  const html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('dialog')
    .setWidth(600)
    .setHeight(600);
  DocumentApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Dialog');
};


Yes, this is achievable.
HTML/CSS/JavaScript is used to create the HtmlOutput object in the client-side code. Use the JavaScript statement google.script.run.openDialog() to open dialog from the Sidebar. It's up to you to include it on an onclick attribute on an HTML, use en event listener or whatever.

I can't say anything specific about the OP case, as the question doesn't include details about the sidebar.
